# Cannot find the docker container log in path provided by docker inspect command?

Tags: docker, airflow

I have created a container for apache-airflow and I wanted to check certain logs of my containerID which I had exited. Idea is to check these logs for unceremonious exit and detect the reason for same using the log.

```
abcd@DESKTOP-3ODJEUD:/var/lib/docker-desktop$ docker inspect 6541ee13b429 | grep -i logpath

"LogPath":     "/var/lib/docker/containers/6541ee13b4292a81e2261522cd501b74b15e12bef89d284ceecf686aa6bc2632/6541ee13b4292a81e2261522cd501b74b15e12bef89d284ceecf686aa6bc2632-json.log",
abcd@DESKTOP-3ODJEUD:/var/lib/docker-desktop$
```

But when i try and see if such a file exist on my system I do not see these log. In-fact the folder /var/lib/docker itself does not seem to exist.

Note I tried to look for it on the WSL (windows subsystem for Linux) which i am using to run the docker command. I am expecting that this is the right place to look as upon exit from container I am expected to land here as I execute my `docker exec` command from the same window.

Note that I have the docker-Desktop installed on my windows machine.

Comment: Docker on Windows is running inside a Linux virtual machine. Paths like `/var/lib/docker` exists inside the VM, not directly on your host.

Comment: I realised right way to do it is to to in docker file mount a path on my machine to the path in container  where logs etc. are written , so that even if container is down one can look into logs on shared drive.